# Embedded HTML code being displayed rather than HTML being rendered

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to use the calendar gem in my project (https://github.com/elevation/event_calendar). But when I open the calendar page, it renders the page by showing the html code of the calendar rather than rendering the html. Basically the source for the page generate is like 
<div class="ec-calendar">
instead of 
.
Can anyone let me know what is going on and how to resolve it.

Comment: Can you post up your view? It might be caused by Rails 3 outputting safe code by default. Try putting `raw` before your helpers.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are using Rails 3? As a security measure against XSS (Cross Site Scripting), Rails 3 renders html inside of strings as text. If you know the html in your string is safe, call html_safe on it, like

```
'<div class="ec-calendar">'.html_safe
```

or

```
raw '<div class="ec-calendar">'
```

html_safe I believe, is preferred over raw. Not sure what's different behind the scenes, if anything.